# When stripping bits out of an int, the compiler warns about one conversion but not others. Is there a workaround?

Tags: c++

In the following code, my compiler is complaining about one of these conversions, but not the others.

```
unsigned ARGB;
unsigned char a( ARGB >> 24 );
unsigned char r( ( ARGB & 0xFF0000 ) >> 16 ); // warning!
unsigned char g( ( ARGB & 0xFF00 ) >> 8 );
unsigned char b( ARGB & 0xFF );
```

The compiler reports "warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'int' to 'char', possible loss of data" ... but only for the second conversion.

I can see why it's doing this, I suppose. `a` and `b` are clearly the result of single operations that only leave 8 significant bits, and in the case of `g`, the bitwise `&` results in 16 significant bits (which could be stored in a `short` without loss) and that result is then shifted right leaving only 8 bits. But the bitwise `&` operation done on `r`, by contrast, leaves an intermediate value with 24 significant bits, which would require an `int` if it were to be stored somewhere. I'm guessing that the compiler treats the shift as a separate process, acting on an integer, and that that's why it is warning about possible loss of data.

Since we treat (almost all) warnings as errors, this is something I need to resolve. Obviously I can use `static_cast` to explicitly document what I want, but that is (in my opinion) an ugly tool, and a sign that the code could be written better.

Does anyone know of a nice, neat, standard-compliant and portable form of code that will perform the required data conversion?

I prefer not to rely on bitfields due to portability concerns.

Comment: Could this be problem with MSVC? Since I couldn't reproduce this issue with both GCC, and clang.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning goes away when the order of the shift and AND is swapped, so:

```
unsigned char r( ( ARGB >> 16) & 0xFF );
```

Comment: Doing the shift before the AND does work for `r` ...but the same pattern would produce a warning for `g`. Perhaps I'm just being a perfectionist?

Comment: @TimRandall that's odd, I didn't get a warning for `unsigned char g( ( ARGB >> 8) & 0xFF )` either, anyway it seems MSVC is pretty inconsistent in its ability to figure out whether these operations are safe..

Comment: So, are you saying that in this form, OP's compiler can assume that the result is a vaild 8-bit value, while in the original form it can't predict that?

Comment: @Bob__ that's what it looks like to me (even though range propagation on the original form does not look hard), but I don't know for sure what the compiler is doing internally, there could be other reasons why the warning goes away

Comment: @harold I retract my previous comment. Reading the answer below makes it clear: doing the mask last makes it very easy for the compiler to see that we're left with 8 bits, because the mask is always the same.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the other answer, changing operations might help, but it comes with another advantage: consistency (and if you consider dropping obsolete parentheses another one, well, a second):

```
unsigned char a( ARGB >> 24         );
unsigned char r( ARGB >> 16 & 0xffU );
unsigned char g( ARGB >>  8 & 0xffU ); // same value as above
unsigned char b( ARGB       & 0xffU ); //      -- " --
```

(You might add masking to first line as well and shifting by 0 to last one and hope for the compiler to optimise them away again – actually, it should do so for all the masks, as you assign to 8-bit-size variable anyway...)

Now back to the warning (which you apparently still did not get rid of): An explicit cast should now really force the compiler to drop it:

```
unsigned char x(static_cast<unsigned char>(argb >> y & 0xffU));
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Seeing that the mask is always the same, it's much easier to see why the compiler wouldn't issue a warning.